# Facebook redirect uri not maintaining my passed values

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

My ultimate goal is to store Facebook user tokens in my DB for use later.  I have no problem with the theory - this helped: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4608713/can-i-store-facebook-access-token-and-use-it-later

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.1.1).

I am having issues passing data to the `redirect_uri` and having that data successfully come back to that url from Facebook.

Code:

```
$args['redirect_uri'] = 'http://tld.com/add.php?id='. $uid .'&filename='. $pfilename .'&gid='. $gid;
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
header("Location: $loginUrl");
```

After Facebook does its work and sends back to my domain I successfully have the user token, but my passed data is lost.

After research I have found this: [on facebook connect login uri, can I add an extra get param on url, and have that passed to my script once user logs in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740539/on-facebook-connect-login-uri-can-i-add-an-extra-get-param-on-url-and-have-that) -- problem is the answer with two votes is what I am doing above and not working.  And as for the second answer, I couldn't get it working by changing my `? to %3F`.

My question is how can this be done and whats the correct working method to accomplish passing data to the Facebook login url using the `redirect_uri` and retrieving that data.

Comment: What about storing your data in a PHP session?

Comment: I would prefer to figure this out by passing via _GET but maybe if this gets no answers I could attempt a session method. Would really like to avoid that though.

Comment: Yes, figured you didn't want too much data in session, which is why this is a comment and not an answer. I nearly always use the JS SDK to manipulate user data, so don't run into this problem - that would be another route you could take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  I had errors in my passing my data.  The theory and everything I described above works fine - you can pass data to the `redirect_uri` just fine.